# Automate setcommands

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Is it possible to automate the setcommands command?
I want to register all my commands on startup of the application, so I don't have to do that manually (which kinda sucks during development).
Is there a HTTP API or can I send a message to the Botfather from my bot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not API method to set commands, you have to use the Botfather.

Comment: but do I have to do that manually or can I send messages to it from my bot?

Comment: No, Bots can't talk to each other because it might cause endless loops.