# Bot information in chat window on telegram before clicking start

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

[image]I want a little bot information to be posted on the chat window, when a user opens up the chat window, and after typing /start that information disappears. How do I do that?

Comment: Please add what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text displayed *before* you start chatting with a bot is the **Bot's description**

---

Use the [@botFather](https://t.me/botfather) to change the description for your bot:

- `/setdescription`
- `/mybots`

  1. Click desired bot
  2. <kbd>Edit Description</kbd>
  3. Send your description as a text message

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gWYj.png)

---

This will then show up if you start chatting with the bot:

[image]

Comment: How do I do it using Python?

Comment: @NehaDeshpande That was not clear from your question. However, there has already been questions here about automating BotFather conversation, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41209343/how-to-create-a-bot-with-in-telegram-with-botfather-and-using-only-a-code) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37231451/automate-setcommands). There should be some with code examples, but can't find them real quick.

Comment: you can also [check my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62214083/11984670)  or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61466182/11984670)  for an sample implementations with python